# Angular 10 Prod Build cant Find Dependancies on Cpanel

Tags: angular

I have run into this before but for the love of me cant remember how I got around it.
Essentially Im Compiling the Build in production to Export to my Cpanel (Test Server) To share the application for testing.

However I get nothing on the server [path](https://azipit.co.za/booking/thorpesfarm/):

Because its a test server I have to go Public html -> Folder -> Application

The only Console response I get is that Resources failed to load so I think its a issue with how im building the application

My Build Command: `npm run build -- --prod --baseHref=/booking/thorpesfarm`

The only Errors/Warnings I get are:

```
Error
DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" - node_modules/tslib/package.json.
```

```
Warning:
src/main.ts depends on 'hammerjs'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

On my angular.json Warning for:

```
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
Unable to load schema from:thorpesfarm/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json': ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
```

Nothing I believe will affect the build from running entirely. Application serve's fine on local no issues. My Insitlation Process is as Follows:

-Clear Dist

-Run Build Command

-Zip Dist Folder

-Upload to Cpanel

-Unpack

-Visit Server Path

**Note:** Previous Version Ran fine on the WebServer There is node Support I Deleted a Note I made with the command I was using for the builds (So Im fairly certain the issue lies here) I have close to 0 Experience/Knowledge when it comes to Production in Angular. Anyone have any ideas What might be happening?

My Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Thorpes Farm</title>
  <base href="./">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <!-- Compiled and minified Materialize CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified Materialize JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script><!-- Google Material Icons --><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"  rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body style="overflow-x:hidden;" class="mat-typography igx-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you check the network tab in chrome, you can see it can't find your compiled scripts because they are wrongly referenced (`https://azipit.co.za/runtime-es2015.js` etc). in the docs the option is named `--base-href` not `baseHref`

Comment: Interesting Tried it Still doesn't seem to be able to to find the scripts. Do u know what causes the refrence issues? Is it the way im building or something in one of my json files

Comment: can you use `ng build --prod --base-href....` instead of `npm run build` ? maybe you got something funny in your package.json scripts

Comment: tried ```ng build  --prod --base-href=/booking/thorpesfarm```  Same Thing Checking package.json name was different from my angular.json changing it and going again

Comment: Your base ```href```  on your ```index.html``` file might be wrong. Try this way ```<base href="./">```

Comment: @KibéM.C updated base ill add my prebuild index.html to the qeustion but after the build href seems to update correctly ```<base href="/booking/thorpesfarm">``` Still not finding the JS Dependancies

Comment: If you cannot find your JS dependencies it means your base href is wrong. You can place your them on your root folder then.

Comment: @KibéM.C oh wow So it was litteraly a missing forward slash on the base should be : booking/thorpesfarm/ not booking/thorpesfarm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Indicated by OP

The issue was resolved by changing the:
Base `href` on his `index.html`

**Incorrect**

`<base href="/booking/thorpesfarm">`

**Correct**

`<base href="/booking/thorpesfarm/">`

In OP's Case the compiler was expecting a `forwardSlash /`  At the end of the `href`.

This means the base `href` on `Index.html` would be as follows:

> `<base href="./">`